# Accidentally poured oil in car's radiator. Can I drive it or should I get it towed?

Tags: oil, radiator

Somehow I managed to get engine oil instead of antifreeze in my car's radiator, about 50-60 ml maybe.

It is a 2004 Fiat Panda which I don't plan keeping for more than a couple of years, so I do not care about really long-term consequences. It is our second car and we keep it as long as we do not have to spend any more serious money on it.

In case it matters, I need to fill the radiator every 3 days as it loses the water (gasket problem I think)

So ... Is it safe to keep driving the car without going to the mechanic?

Comment: It's not that expensive to replace the coolant, you can even do it at home. If you really just dropped about 50mL it's probably safe to drive it to the mechanic, since coolants volume vary but are usually a couple liters (my car for example takes 6L)

Comment: Have them do a cooling system flush after they fix the leak, which is important to get the leak fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please search the site ... I believe this topic has been EXTENSIVELY covered.